# SSO to Office 365 Android Apps on ChromeOS

Tags: android, azure-active-directory, office365, office365-apps, androidappsonchromeos

I'm working on a project where employees will receive Chromebooks. The plan is to use the native Office 365 Android Apps.

The Chromebooks are configured to authenticate against Azure AD which is configured by using this document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/google-apps-tutorial

Everything works like it should and I can SSO to the Office 365 portal (portal.office.com) and use all my Office 365 apps.

However, I would like this to work for the Android apps as well, e.g. if the user starts Excel for Android, to have it SSO sign-in as well.

The problem is here that the user account also exists in Google and it uses that account to access the Play Store and Android apps, not the Azure AD account.

Any idea how to accomplish this or is this just plain impossible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be any official documentation on this. However, my experience from my Android phone and Chromebook is that there is SSO between the Office365 apps even if it doesn't SSO from the initial Chromebook login. So they may need to sign into one of the apps, but from there the login will transfer between them. That login is also good for a period of time based on your O365 policies.

What that means for your users is that during initial setup they may need to log in twice- once for the Chromebook and once for the Android apps. After that they will only need to log in once to the Chromebook and occassionaly refresh their credentials for the apps.